# Save Simulink model as XML file

Tags: matlab, simulink

I have a simulink model with me, and I need to generate an XML file from this model for the purpose of comparison.

I tried the following list of commands -

```
>> model = 'simple_model_1'; % simple_model_1 is the name of the model
>> open_system(model); % model must be in the current folder or matlab path
>> save_system(model, 'simple_model_1.xml', 'ExportToXML', true);
```

But I'm getting the following error: Warning: The 'ExportToXML' option is no longer supported and will be removed in a future release.

I am working with MATLAB 2018a. Please let me know if there is any way to generate an XML file from a model with this release of MATLAB.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The correct way to do model comparison is to use the [model comparison tool](https://uk.mathworks.com/help/simulink/ug/compare-simulink-model-xml-files.html). The corresponding command-line function is [`visdiff`](https://uk.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/visdiff.html). The model comparison tool operates directly onto the `*.slx` files, there's no need to export to XML (this is done internally by the tool).

Answer (score 2):

If your model extension is `slx`, you can use unzip using the `unzip` command to decompress your model into several files. In the `simulink` folder, you will find your XML file : `blockdiagram.xml`.